# Magento 2 Elasticsearch: Root mapping definition has unsupported

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalogsearch, magento2.1.6

I am trying to setup elasticsearch 2.4.5 on a internal server and trying to use this for my EE 2.1.6 setup (magento installed in my local version). Following are the ES details.

```
{
  "name" : "The Grip",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "TtY4Vl4LRJ22V5wF1fhkOQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.5",
    "build_hash" : "c849dd13904f53e63e88efc33b2ceeda0b6a1276",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-04-24T16:18:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I try reindexing I get the following error.

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
mapper_parsing_exception: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [
  from: 0
][
  size: 10000
][
  stored_fields: [
    _id,
    _score
  ]
][
  query: {
    bool={
      should=[
        {
          match={
            sku=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            _all=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            color=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            description=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            manufacturer=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            name=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            short_description=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            status_value=shirt
          }
        },
        {
          match={
            tax_class_id_value=shirt
          }
        }
      ],
      minimum_should_match=1
    }
  }
][
  aggregations: {
    price_bucket={
      extended_stats={
        field=price_0_1
      }
    },
    category_bucket={
      terms={
        field=category_ids
      }
    }
  }
]
```

When I do it again then I get the following error.
    Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
    illegal_argument_exception: Alias action [match] not supported

When I try using search on the store front it gives me an exception.

```
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception): 
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index":"magento2_product_1"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index":"magento2_product_1"},"status":404}
```

The above exception makes sense as Magento is looking for index `magento2_product_1` and in ES the index created is `magento2_product_1_v1`.

Does anyone know what the error is really about? Why Magento is not able to create the index fully.

Comment: First make sure that the Elasticsearch supports Magento EE version 2.1.x.
From their documentation,                           

`If you get the Elasticsearch software from the Elasticsearch Linux repository, we support versions 2.x.
If you get the Elasticsearch software from their Elasticsearch-PHP repository, we support the 2.0 branch.`

Comment: @Elavarasan - I have followed the docs provided by Magento on the [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com). Unless they haven't updated the doc for the newer Magneto version or if something is missing on my end it should be working fine as per the configurations we have in the Devdocs.

Comment: have try to in reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

@Rajith: "magento2_product_1" is the alias of "magento2_product_1_v1" the index that is created on ES is correct. Magento should be able to find the 
correct index through the alias "magento2_product_1".

It is working without any issues on Magento Devbox which uses Elastic Search 2.4.5 and I am running Magento EE 2.1.6.

There should be something wrong in your Elastic Search configuration or the permissions.

Comment: The issue is with alias. When I checked the index value for "magento2_product_1_v1" I couldn't find any alias assigned to it.

Comment: @Nirmal : Can you help me setting up elastic search on my magento instance ? here is the link to the question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184306/magento-2-ee-elastic-search-not-resulting-products-in-search-suggestion