# Magento 2 EE elastic search module not enabled

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, magento-enterprise-2, elasticsearch

I am running Magento 2.1.2 Enterprise Edition instance.

I have installed and enabled elastic search on the same. When I click on TEST CONNECTION button it says Successful! Test Again?

However the search suggestions does not display product names.

Do I need some additional settings or information to pass to elastic search?

[image]

Configuration for Elastic Search in Admin:

[image]

```
name    "My First Node"
cluster_name    "mycluster1"
version 
number  "2.3.1"
build_hash  "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39"
build_timestamp "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "5.5.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Magento 2.x only supports Elasticsearch 2.3

> We support Elasticsearch versions 1.4, 1.7, and 2.4. The default version is 1.7.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/project/project-conf-files_services-elastic.html#plugins

Which is a disappointment, because AWS supports 2.4.